# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на один из элементов, которые обрабатываются событием, он один оставался доступным, а другие блокировались?

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

```
$('#one, #two, #three').click(function(){});
```

Нужно получить список элементов, к которому привязано данное событие с этой функцией.

**UPD:**

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на один из элементов, которые обрабатываются этим событием, он один оставался доступным, а другие блокировались.

Comment: тут у вас не элементы, а событие вызывает функцию

Comment: Быть может автор имел ввиду как в функции понять на каком элементе произошёл клик? Если да, то смотрить в target: `click(function(e){console.log(e.target)});`

Comment: *... список всех элементов, которые вызывают функцию* - '#one, #two, #three'. Уточните пожалуйста Ваш вопрос подробнее.

Comment: Я имел ввиду, внутри функции, которая вызывается событием click, узнать все элементы, у которых сработает событие click (в данном случае: one, two, three) .

Comment: что значит сработает? Сработает оно только тогда, когда соответствующий элемент будет нажат. Зачем вам знать, где еще назначен данный обработчик клика? вы уверены, что вам именно это надо?

Comment: @teran, да, мне это и надо, чтобы после клика я мог исключить элемент, который я нажал от элементов, которые еще не нажаты. Можно конечно другие методы для этого использовать, но то, о чем я хочу узнать самый короткий.

Comment: дак надо снять обработчик с текущего элемента тогда и все. Либо помечать классом, или атрибутом.

Comment: Ваше желание совсем не совпадает с заголовком вопроса и текстом в вопросе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> мне это и надо, чтобы после клика я мог исключить элемент, который я нажал от элементов, которые еще не нажаты

Если под данной фразой понимается, что фактически обработчик нужно выполнить только единожды для каждого элемента, то можно рассмотреть несколько путей решения данной задачи.

**Первый:**
*при клике устанавливать атрибут, обозначающий, что обработчик уже был вызван для данного элемента.*

```js
$("#one, #two, #three").click(function(){
   var done = $(this).data('done');
   if(done) return;
   console.log($(this).attr('id') + ' clicked');
   $(this).data('done', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="one">btn 1</button>
<button id="two">btn 2</button>
<button id="three">btn 3</button>
```

**Второй:**
*обозначить все элементы одним классом, обработчик прикрепить к общему родителю указав класс как селектор. При клике, убирать класс с элемента.*

```js
$("#wrapper").on('click', '.active', function(){
   $(this).removeClass('active');
   console.log( $(this).attr('id') + ' clicked' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <button id="one" class="active">btn 1</button>
    <button id="two" class="active">btn 2</button>
    <button id="three" class="active">btn 3</button>
</div>
```

**Третий:**
*отключить обработчик от элемента как таковой - самый короткий вариант.*

```js
$("#one, #two, #three").click(function(e){

   console.log( $(this).attr('id') + ' clicked');
   
   $(this).off(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="one">btn 1</button>
    <button id="two">btn 2</button>
    <button id="three">btn 3</button>
```

Если все же речь о том, чтобы оставить обработчик, но при этом знать, что для данного элемента событие уже выполнялось, то остаются варианты - пометить `data`-атрибутом, либо добавить некоторый класс к элементу.

```
$("...").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    // или
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

в дальнейшем, получая значение атрибута, либо проверяя наличие класса `.hasClass('active')`

> нужно чтобы при нажатии на один из элементов, которые обрабатываются этим событием, он один оставался доступным, а другие блокировались. И для этого мне нужно узнать, какие именно элементы в обработчике.

Наиболее простым и понятным будет вариант с общим обработчиком на родительском элементе, и удаления класса у остальных элементов. Хотя и вариант с `off` должен быть аналогичен.

```js
$("#wrapper").on('click', '.active', function(){

   console.log( $(this).attr('id') ) ;
   
   $('.active').not( $(this) ).removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
        <button id="one" class="active">btn 1</button>
        <button id="two" class="active">btn 2</button>
        <button id="three" class="active">btn 3</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Смотри мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на один из элементов, которые обрабатываются этим событием, он один оставался доступным, а другие блокировались. И для этого мне нужно узнать, какие именно элементы в обработчике. Вариант с классом попробую.

Comment: @SoulHistory дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо за помощь и потраченное время!

Comment: @Alex будьте аккуратнее с форматированием кода. Не надо весь код форматировать под какие-то ваши собственные представления и предпочтения. Пробелы и переносы строк, которые вы так старательно удалили, призваны отделить логические блоки повысить читаемость кода. И в целом почитайте, когда надо и не надо править вопросы/ответы. Правки должны улучшать, а не курсив добавлять.

Comment: @teran у Вас первоначально была опечатка в одном слове, остальное попутно добавлено как раз-таки чтобы повысить читаемость (сравните до и после). Честно говоря непонятно как отделение строки `console.log(...)` от другого кода и только в одном коде ответа улучшает его читаемость`, но если это по-Вашему нанесло вред Вашем ответу приношу свои извинения.

Comment: непонятно, почему среди вариантов с отключением обработчика нет метода `$(..).one('click',...)` который сам себя отключает потом